# Accessing data from other classes

Tags: java, class, variables, private

Im a beginner so please be **VERY** specific. Anyway i have three code classes here and i want to acces data from c-b then b-a E.g.

```
class GoobyPls {
{
    private int CHealth = 20;
    private int MHealth = 20;
    private int CAgility = 10;
    private int MAgility = 10;
    private int CDefence = 5;
    private int MDefence = 5;
}   
}

class Stats {
public static void foo() {
    string Health =  CHealth + "/" + MHealth ;
    string Agility = CAgility + "/" + MAgility;
    string Defence = CDefence + "/" + MDefence;
}

}

class ViewStats {
public static void foo() {
System.out.println("Health");
                System.out.println(Health);
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("Agility");
                System.out.println(Agility);
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("Defence");
                System.out.println(Defence);
                System.out.println(" ");
  }
}
```

So `GoobyPls` is `a`, `Stats` is `b` and `ViewStats` is `c`

also i cant put it all in one class because eventually there will be a modifier class to edit `CHealth`, `MHealth` etc

Comment: Here's [a good place to start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: Also, adhere to [java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

Comment: Why are the code to calculate e.g. health and the numbers it needs in different classes?

Comment: Just for flexibility and ease of acces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class `GoobyPls` add getters for each item as following:

```
class GoobyPls {
{
   private int CHealth = 20;

   public int getHealth(){
      return Chealth;
   }
}
```

and then in `viewStats` do this:

```
GoodyPls gp = new GoobyPls();
System.out.println(gp.getHealth());
```

just call getters whenever when you want to use a private variable. Or you can also define the variables public, so that you can directly call them in viewStats. But getters and setters are better as a design point of view, since hiding information is better.
Fields should be declared private unless there is a good reason for *not* doing so.

Comment: To clarify: Some reasons non-public fields and hiding information is *usually* better include: a) Internals are hidden from the outside, so you can change fields and internal implementation around later without changing the rest of your code that may use your getters. b) You have the ability to write getters but not setters, effectively making data read-only, which can be useful. c) Subclasses can override methods, but cannot override public field access. Still there are many situations where public fields make sense. Careful with statements like "always better" when teaching new programmers.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest reading through the [Java tutorial on classes and objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), which will give you a good basis to work from.

The most basic way to pass data between classes is to define public methods in your class that other objects can call to get access to your data. For example:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName; 
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName () {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName () {
        return lastName;
    }

}
```

Methods with names like `getX()` that return values are called "getters". Then, in another class, you can access that data, for example:

```
public void elsewhere () {
    Person p = new Person();
    System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());
}
```

Another way to communicate with classes is to write methods that take parameters, e.g.:

```
public void printFullName (Person p) {
    System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());
}

public void elsewhere () {
    Person p = new Person();
    printFullName(p);
}
```

You may also want to provide methods to *set* data in an object. These are called "setters" and are the counterpart to "getters". Building on `Person` from above:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName; 
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName () {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName () {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName (String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName (String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Then, other objects can modify a person's data, e.g.:

```
public void elsewhere () {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setFirstName("Bob");
    System.out.println(p.getFirstName()); // prints "Bob"
}
```

Here's an example using everything from above:

```
public void swapPersonFirstAndLastName (Person p) {
    String temporary = p.getFirstName();
    p.setFirstName(p.getLastName());
    p.setLastName(temporary);
}

public void printFullName (Person p) {
    System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());
}

public void example () {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setFirstName("John");
    p.setLastName("Smith");
    swapPersonFirstAndLastName(p);
    printFullName(p); // prints Smith John
}
```

Hope that helps and good luck. Read those tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the private variable outside the class, you must use the getter method like below.

```
class GoobyPls {
private int CHealth = 20;
private int MHealth = 20;
private int CAgility = 10;
private int MAgility = 10;
private int CDefence = 5;
private int MDefence = 5;
public int getCHealth() {
    return CHealth;
}
public int getMHealth() {
    return MHealth;
}
public int getCAgility() {
    return CAgility;
}
public int getMAgility() {
    return MAgility;
}
public int getCDefence() {
    return CDefence;
}
public int getMDefence() {
    return MDefence;
}
}
```

Below is your State class

```
class Stats {
public static void foo() {
GoobyPls g=new GoobyPls();
int Health =  g.getCHealth() / g.getMHealth() ;
int Agility = g.getCAgility() / g.getMAgility();
int Defence = g.getCDefence() / g.getMDefence();
}
```

and in your `viewstat` class's `foo()` method you can access the about value by `State.Health`,`State.Agility` and `State.Defence`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't you private field like follows

```
 class GoobyPls {
{
    private int CHealth = 20;  // you can't use private here
    private int MHealth = 20;   // and care on java naming conventions
    private int CAgility = 10;
    private int MAgility = 10;
    private int CDefence = 5;
    private int MDefence = 5;
}
}
```

and it should be `String` not string

```
   string Health =  CHealth + "/" + MHealth ; // String not string
```

Use IDE to do coding it will help you to identify those kind of issue by your own.

Comment: To clarify: The reason `private` can't be used there is because there is a second inner set of curly braces, which actually marks an initialization block (which is a different topic), and `private` is not a legal modifier there. They would have to be moved up into the class.

Comment: Thanks looking into IDE now

Comment: @JasonC ohh Thanks for adding more info

Comment: @user2687097 Check out Eclipse or NetBeans or JCreator.

Answer (score -1):

Put getters and setters to your class.Or make fields public.(i don't suggest the second)

```
class GoobyPls {

    public int getCHealth() {
        return CHealth;
    }
    public void setCHealth(int cHealth) {
        CHealth = cHealth;
    }
    public int getMHealth() {
        return MHealth;
    }
    public void setMHealth(int mHealth) {
        MHealth = mHealth;
    }
    public int getCAgility() {
        return CAgility;
    }
    public void setCAgility(int cAgility) {
        CAgility = cAgility;
    }
    public int getMAgility() {
        return MAgility;
    }
    public void setMAgility(int mAgility) {
        MAgility = mAgility;
    }
    public int getCDefence() {
        return CDefence;
    }
    public void setCDefence(int cDefence) {
        CDefence = cDefence;
    }
    public int getMDefence() {
        return MDefence;
    }
    public void setMDefence(int mDefence) {
        MDefence = mDefence;
    }
    private int CHealth = 20;
    private int MHealth = 20;
    private int CAgility = 10;
    private int MAgility = 10;
    private int CDefence = 5;
    private int MDefence = 5;
}
```

Then you can access like this:

```
class Stats {
public static void foo() {
GoobyPls gbp=new GoobyPls();
    string Health =  gbp.getCHealth + "/" + MHealth ;
    string Agility = gbp.getCAgility + "/" + MAgility;
    string Defence = gbp.getCDefence + "/" + MDefence;
}
```

Comment: where do these etters and seters go, could you edit my code to shw me pleae??